# Is there an eslint rule for TypeScript error TS2345

Tags: typescript, eslint

Is there an eslint rule to check for the typescript error TS2345? For example when an interface does not have all the required values.

```
Argument of type '{ toValue: number; fieldName: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SomeConfig'.
  Property 'otherProp' is missing in type '{ toValue: number; fieldName: number; }' but required in type 'SomeConfig'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: Why do you want an eslint Rule if the compiler itself is notifying you about that issue in the first place?

Comment: Vscode is notifying the error but the compiler is not and eslint does not, knowing the tslint rule that turns this check on or off would be an alternative

Comment: That IS in actual compiler error, so your compiler settings outside of VSCode seem to be wrong or not strict enough. I propose you analyze this rather than trying to find a bandaid rule for eslint.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic is right. In order to create such a rule correctly, you would have to host the typescript language service inside your rule, which is neither logical nor viable.

Comment: If you hace that object which is missing a property of a type, use inheritance to extend the actual type with that `useNativeDriver` or mark it as nullable `useNativeDriver?: ...`. Tricking the compiler is never a good option. You are trying to mask all Typescript's power, and you should not.

Comment: The compiler is not notifying me @ChristianIvicevic So assuming it's disabled for some reason. Also I know that tslint is being replaced by eslint and was hoping there was an alternative.

Comment: If some knows what rule controls TS2345 or how to find out what rule controls it then I can find out what is wrong with the tslint and or eslint configuration.

Comment: @VRoxa The question is about what rule controls this check not the error it's self. I know how to fix it. I just want the tslint check to show it.

Comment: @AluanHaddad The question is about what rule controls TS2345

Comment: The TS2345 rule you are referring to has nothing to do with any linter. It's a compiler error code.

Comment: It is possible to suppress the error in various ways but that should be a last resort. This is not a configurable check, it's foundational to the type system.

Answer (score 0):

so I got this error trying to use the Animated API when running react-native-web using Typescript.
If that is your case, then I can confidently tell you that the solution to this is to set native driver to false.
`useNativeDriver: false`

Comment: The question is about how to see this error, not about this specific error

Answer (score 0):

There is no eslint rule to check this error and for this error to be triggered a build of the TypeScript project is required. Adding
"build": "tsc -p ." to the "scripts" section of your package.json will allow you to run yarn build to display this error.